# how do i solve? subscripted assignment dimension mismatch error

Tags: image, matlab, matrix

I am new to this forum. Let me get started: I work on MATLAB and keep getting errors all the time. Finally i found a good forum like yours. My problem is this: I have an image which I want to put inside a large matrix. Everytime I do it I get

```
??? ERROR: subscripted assignment dimension mismatch
```

I tried everything possible, like u say `resize`, `repmat`, `reshape`....but I could not guess what is going wrong.

My code is like this:

```
nem(:,:,1) = image  %// <-- error subscripted assignment dimension mismatch
```

my size of `image` is

```
71 * 71 
bytes :----40328
class :----double
```

`nem` is created by

```
nem = zeros([size(inputimage,1),size(inputimage,2),12]);
```

size of `inputmage` is

```
[m,n,o] = size(inputimage);
m = 584    n = 565    o = 1
```

and size of `nem`:

```
[m,n,o] = size(img_out);
m = 584   n = 565   o = 12
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to "fit" `image` a 71-by-71 matrix into `mem(:,:,1)` which is 584-by-565 matrix.
How do you expect Matlab to do this type of assignment??

You can fit `image` into a **part** of `mem`

```
>> mem( 1:size(image,1), 1:size(image,2), 1 ) = image
```

Comment: Maybe you mean : `mem( 1:size(image,1), 1:size(image,2), 1 ) = image` and for the Asker, try to avoid using image as variable name, image is a matlab function too. Try to use a different name.